# Android: TextView and Html not working properly

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview where I have to display some html greek letters

Something like this(without the spaces):

> & epsilon;& phi;& alpha;& rho;

My problem is that the letter & phi; is not showing at all. Every other letter works fine but this doesn't come up. It's just a space. And I'm sure that is spelled correct because on println works fine and also when a paste here the letter it showed fine. I'm using the Html.toHtml() function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First, I presume that you mean `Html.fromHtml()`, as `Html.toHtml()` takes a `Spanned` and creates HTML from it.

Second, [`Html.fromHtml()` does not do anything itself with entity references](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java). It may be that the underlying [TagSoup parser](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/), which handles parsing HTML, is doing something with some of the entity references but not all. Note that [Android's edition of TagSoup](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tagsoup/) may not be the same as the current one on the TagSoup site.

You might try the Unicode entity equivalent, to see if that helps.